# Convert Tuples to List in a List

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

Right now, I have a list of tuples and sublist below:

```
my_list = [([1, 5], 10), ([2, 8], 12), ([4, 9], 11), ([8, 2], 10)]
```

However, I want the following output below instead:

```
my_list = [[1, 5, 10], [2, 8, 12], [4, 9, 11], [8, 2, 10]]
```

How do I convert this? Please help. Thank you!

Comment: What have you [tried](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3929826) so far?

Answer (score 4):

You can get the desired result as below using list comprehension

```
>>> my_list = [([1, 5], 10), ([2, 8], 12), ([4, 9], 11), ([8, 2], 10)]
>>> 
>>> result = [ [*a, b] for a, b in my_list]
>>> result
[[1, 5, 10], [2, 8, 12], [4, 9, 11], [8, 2, 10]]
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

there is predifined method wich convert a list to a tuple or vise versa , but your list contains imbedded lists so this method works , you iterate over the list and and append to it the a new list using the spread operator *

```
l=[([1, 5], 10), ([2, 8], 12), ([4, 9], 11), ([8, 2], 10)]
newList=[]
for i in l:
    newList.append([*i[0],i[1]])
print(newList)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use this method:

```
new_list = list(map(lambda i : [*i[0],i[1]], my_list))
```

Answer (score 1):

like @sahasrara62 proposes, you can simply use the list comprehension

```py
result = [[*a, b] for a, b in my_list]
```

What I find sometimes practical is to map nested lists to different items like that

```py
result = [[a,b,c] for (a, b), c in my_list]
```

Using this pattern you have the freedom to mix the order of the elements as you wish or even use only a subset of the items which isn't possible with the first approach. See

```py
# mix the order
result = [[b, c, a] for (a, b), c in my_list]
# or omit b for instance
result = [c, a] for (a, b), c in my_list
```